# ios - load two images from URL at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, imageview

I am beginner in objective c. I have two image URLs. First is small size(image for placeholder) image and second is high size (for actual image). We know that, set single image from URL at a time and code is :

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:decoded]
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_placeholder_png]];
```

but I want load image from URL also for placeholderImageg. Any suggestion will be great. Thanks in advance .

Comment: But while loading both images your imageview would have no image for a short period of time. Are you sure you want that? and there are various ways you can do that.

Comment: @ Saheb , Yes I want do this. I can wait for short time.

Comment: Ok So let me get this straight, you will show no image in your imageview at first, then download the thumbnail and original image together, and as the thumbnail is smaller in size, you will show it ASAP, and then after the origianal image is downloaded you will show it. Right?

Comment: downloaded placeholder beats the purpose of placeholders :D.. better to follow the normal way of having a loading icon or something to show in placeholder. it works for users as well for devs.

Comment: last question- are you using tableview? or is this about images in tableview cell?

Comment: @ Saheb I am using UICollectionview cell.

Comment: just download the whole placeholder images first, then only download the full image in background then replace it to the low quality placeholder...

Answer (score 0):

If you display two images at same time use this "http://khanlou.com/2012/08/asynchronous-downloaded-images-with-caching/" but you can set unique cache key for every image.